# How to install stable tazlito on Debian Stretch via Internet?

Tags: debian, slitaz

I didn't found tazlito in the [official stable packages list](https://packages.debian.org/stable/allpackages?format=txt.gz) but Internet provide some historical information about in Debian tazlito use cases.

How to install it on Stretch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously tazlito doesn't provide packages for [Another Distribution](http://doc.slitaz.org/en:handbook:genlivecd#installing-tazlito-on-another-distribution).

It can be build manually:

- download specific *tar.gz* from [sources](http://download.tuxfamily.org/slitaz/sources/tazlito/).
- unpack *tar.gz* via `tar -xvzf <tazlito>.tar.gz`.
- `cd <tazlito> && make install DESTDIR=/path/to/install/destination/directory`

Finally you will have fully installed tazlito in `/path/to/install/destination/directory`.

P.S. If you skip `DESTDIR=...` parameter then tazlito will be installed in the following system directories:

- `/usr/sbin`
- `/usr/share/doc`

P.P.S.

Maybe you prefer to build your own package from tazlito `tar.gz` and install this package via `dpkg`, then please read about how to build your own packages in the [Debian New Maintainers' Guide](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/).